# React router and PropType validation of variables that haven't been initialized

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Let's say I have a variable that is uninitialized

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState();
```

I have two routes. One is to a signup page which will populate the email, and another is to a page that says "Thanks for registering, please check {props.email"

```
<Switch>
  <Route path=...>
    <SignupForm onSubmit={(email)=>setEmail(email)} />
  </Route
  <Route path=...>
    <RegisterComplete email={email} />
  </Route
</Switch>
```

Now, the problem is that `RegisterComplete` has the email proptype set to required, because you don't want to render that page unless you have an email passed in.

However, since all routes are immediately passed as children to the Switch, prop types will throw a warning saying you're missing the email.

I don't want to remove the `isRequired` from proptypes and I find that using a default is just a hack that defeats the purpose of proptypes, eg `const [email, setEmail] = useState("");`

What is the best way to resolve this proptypes warning?

Comment: You can set the initialState to null or use the defaultProps when you define the propTypes so when no value is passed it will assign one automatically.

Comment: What would the default be though? Blank string would be an error condition and defeats the point of isRequired

Comment: Oh you are right mate, I don't think mark that prop as required and do not initialize it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The point of using required proptype is that you need to pass that prop for the component to render. There are two ways of handling that:

1. Initialize prop and deal with the initialized value inside the component if needed
2. Don't render the route/component while your prop is undefined

PropTypes are developer helpers, they don't control the business flow.

Comment: 2) is happening already. react router's <Switch> does not render the component that doesn't have the props passed in. proptype validation however, occurs the moment a component is instantiated regardless of whether it's rendered

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up going with is this:

Unless there are checks in place, it is possible for the user to land on RegisterComplete. If we lived in the old world of templating, the backend API would 300 the user to the registration page. We should follow this pattern in the frontend as well.

We allow email to be blankstring.

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
```

Next we check for blankstring in `RegisterComplete` and redirect.

```
export default function RegisterComplete(props) {
    if (!props.email) {
        props.redirectToRegistration();
    }
};
```

And then on the main router we pass in that redirection callable

```
<Switch>
  ...
  <Route path=...>
    <RegisterComplete email={email}
                      redirectToRegistration={() => history.push('/signup/')}/>
  </Route
</Switch>
```

Now we pass the proptypes check and the user is properly taken out of a page s/he shouldn't be on. Win!

Philosophically the component proptypes makes sense. email is required but doesn't have to be filled because redirectToRegistration is required and handles that case.